# Save Column Names of a Table in an array using LINQ in entity model with C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am new to C# just started a week ago ... Searched around for 2 days now but didnt find any useful help. I have made a data model which has 3 tables. I am trying to get the names of columns in a particular table in an array.

I would prefer something like:

```
MISSEntities ms= New MISSEntities();

var List= from m in ms.TableName
          select m.Column names;
```

i want result something like the List has name of columns eg. Name, address, phone number

Comment: http://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/entity-framework-get-mapped-table-name-from-an-entity/

Comment: Bartosz- it doesnt even help a bit. as i said i am a novice and the link doesnt have any relation to my problem. thank u

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will work with EF, but try : `var columns = (from dm in Mapping.GetTable(typeof(MISSEntities)).RowType.DataMembers where dm.DbType != null  select dm.MappedName ).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the fields in the model class that is created via EF to represent the database table.

```
var fieldNameList = typeof(YourTableName).GetFields().Select(f=> f.Name);
```

The fields in the class that is mapped to the database table should be the same as your columns in the database table. The class that was created should be the same name as the database table name.

Comment: field names do not have to be the same as their bound column in EF. this solution is fine if you don't do anything fancy. keep in mind that using reflecting takes a bit of 'effort', so you might want to cache the field name list and not call code like this often.